# How to load a d3-dependent script using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, requirejs

I'm trying to load [`d3-path`](https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js) using RequireJS. Looking at the minified `d3-path` source code, it looks like it's AMD-compliant since I see this in the first line:

```
!function(t,s){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?s(exports):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],s):s(t.d3=t.d3||{})}
```

My `index.html` looks like

```
<script>
    require.config({
        paths: {
            "d3": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min",
            "d3-path": "https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min",
            "underscore": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min",
            "jquery": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"
        }
    });
</script>
```

And my JS file that I'm trying to load `d3.path()` looks like

```
require([
    "d3",
    "d3-path",
    "underscore"
],
function(
    d3,
    d3_path,
    _
) {
    // d3, d3_path, and _ are defined
    // but d3.path() isn't defined 
});
```

I can use `d3-path` by doing `d3_path.path()` but I would ideally like to do `d3.path()`. However if I set both `d3` and `d3-path` to `d3` then `d3-path` overrides `d3` and I lose the main `d3` functions.

I'm also open to RequireJS best practices since I'm not sure if I'm using the best method. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preliminary note : you're trying to load d3 V3 with a V4 module, that's not going to mesh very well.

Onto your question : that's the way it is intended to work when you use the micro modules. You load isolated functionalities and combine them.

You only get a `d3` global when you use the [vanilla environments](https://github.com/d3/d3-path#installing) as said in the docs: try

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "d3": "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min"
    }
});

require(['d3'], function(myd3) {
    console.log(window.d3); // undefined
    console.log(myd3); // d3 object
});
```

Note that if you load the whole d3 v4 library, you will get `d3.path` :

```
require(['d3'], function(myd3) {
    console.log(myd3.path); // function
});
```

Finally, if you intend to use multiple micro modules, you could use a mapped configuration:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3src: 'https://d3js.org'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'd3':  'd3src/d3.v4.min',
            'd3-selection':  'd3src/d3-selection.v1.min',
            'd3-path': 'd3src/d3-path.v1.min',
        }
    }
});


// if you want to load the selection and the path modules
require(['d3-selection', 'd3-path'], function(selection, path) {
    // ...
});

// if you want to load d3
require(['d3'], function(d3) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: can i load only d3/path for example?, without load 'd3'?

Comment: @drmartin You can, but you will only have access to the functionalities given by d3.path, you won't have the rest of d3. Try the last exemple without loading d3 and see where that goes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to nikoshr's answer on using d3 micro libraries: You should name the d3 modules in hyphens style, e.g. `d3-selection`, because some d3 libraries depend on other ones and `require` them in this syntax.

Moreover you can create your own `d3` object in your modules, so you don't have to change your code and can use `d3.path()`.

```
require(['d3-selection', 'd3-path'], function(d3Selection, d3Path) {
    let d3 = Object.assign({}, d3Selection, d3Path);

    d3.path();
});
```

Comment: The OP is already "nam[ing] the d3 modules in hyphens style". What specific problem that the OP presented are you addressing?

Comment: @Louis The first point relates to nikoshr's answer, he is using slashes instead. Unfortunately I cannot comment on his answer. The questioner wanted to use `d3.path()` instead of `d3_path.path()`, which is solved by `Object.assign()`.